# C - How to write linked list pointer contents to a text file

Tags: c

I have a program that has an array of pointers such as:

```
INTLIST* myArray[countOfRows];
```

each `myArray` pointer points to a linked list, basically it becomes an M*N matrix.

So for example:

```
3 2 1
2 1 0
1 9 8
```

So `myArray[0]` is a linked list with `3->2->1` and `myArray[1]` is a linked list with `2->1->0..` and so on.  I have a function that prints the matrix which basically does this:

```
for(int i = 0; i<countOfRows; i++)
   list_print(myArray[i]);
```

And then my list_print function is like so:

```
 void list_print(INTLIST* list)
  { /* This function simply prints the linked list out */
     INTLIST* temp=NULL;  //temp pointer to head of list

     /* loops through each node of list printing its datum value */
     for(temp=list; temp!=NULL; temp=temp->next)
        {
           printf("%d ", temp->datum);         //print datum value
        }
     printf("\n");
  }
```

This is all great and working fine, (I know i could optimize and clean up and I promise to do so).  Now my next question is I need to write this matrix out to a text file.  So I tried this:

```
 char* outputFileName = "out.txt";
 FILE* ofp;

 ofp=fopen(outputFileName, "w");

 if(ofp == NULL) 
 {
        printf("Cannot open writeable file!");
        return -1;
 }

 for(i=0; i<fileLineCount; i++)
  {
     fprintf(ofp, list_print(aList[i]);
  }
```

But I take it its not that simple.  Can anyone show me how to print this out to a text file...

Thanks

Comment: +1 to all I know that printf doesnt write to text file but +1 to all

Comment: This is not a linked list, it is a list of pointers.  In a linked list, each element contains a pointer to the next element.

Comment: Random advice: once you have the file enabled version working to your satisfaction, switch the standard output version to a wrapper that just calls the file version with `stdout`. This will leave you with only one copy of that code to maintain. The principle here is DRY: Don't Repeat Yourself!

Comment: @gary: The is the nth in a series of questions the `INTLIST` type *is* a linked list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `fprintf` function in your `list_print` function using a `FILE *` parameter as shown in the example:

```
void list_print(INTLIST* list, FILE *fp)
  { /* This function simply prints the linked list out */
     INTLIST* temp=NULL;  //temp pointer to head of list

     /* loops through each node of list printing its datum value */
     for(temp=list; temp!=NULL; temp=temp->;next)
        {
           fprintf(fp, "%d ", temp->datum);         //print datum value
        }
     fprintf(fp, "\n");
  }
```

Would be done like this:

```
int main(){
   FILE *fp;
   fp = fopen("data.txt", "w");
   for(i=0; i<fileLineCount; i++)
   {
      list_print(alist[i], fp);
   }
   fclose(fp);
}
```

Or

If you wish to retain the binary dump of the linked list from memory to disk (this is the simple way of explaining it), top off my head:

```
for(i=0; i<fileLineCount; i++)
{
     fwrite(alist[i], sizeof(alist[i]), 1, ofp);
}
```

Then when reading from it,

```
for(i=0; i<fileLineCount; i++)
{
     fread(&alist[i], sizeof(alist[i]), 1, ofp);
}
```

**Edit:** I was hesitant to include the above, but ***paxdiablo*** pointed out a flaw in my `fread(...)` and `fwrite(...)` code above, and realized he is right. When doing the binary write of the linked list, the memory addresses references in the linked-list will be invalid when read in the next time. ***Thanks paxdiablo***!

Comment: @tommieb, if those fwrites in the binary dump contain memory addresses (for the links), they will almost certainly be invalid when read back in.

Comment: @paxdiablo: that's true, yes, I did ponder that when writing the answer...Thanks for your input...will amend the answer to highlight your point-out...

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `printf` function to write to file. You need to replace all `printf` calls with `fprintf` and pass the `FILE` pointer along of course.

You can change the `list_print` to accept `FILE*` so you can write your data to file. Something according to this scheme:

```
void list_print(FILE* fp, INTLIST* list)
{
    /* ... rest of your code */

    fprintf(fp, "%d ", temp->datum); 

    /* ... rest of your code */
}
```

Comment: You can still easily emulate the old behaviour with this function by calling *list_print(stdout, thelist)* instead of 
*list_print(thelist)*.

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of things I would do to your `list_print` function:

- pass a `FILE*` variable so you can specify where the file is to go.
- not initialise `temp` to `NULL` since you set it in the `for` statement anyway.

That would give you something like:

```
void list_print(FILE *fOut, INTLIST* list) {
    INTLIST *temp;
    for (temp = list; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next)
        fprintf (fOut, "%d ", temp->datum);
    fprintf (fOut, "\n");
}
```

In order to use it to print to the standard output, just use:

```
list_print (stdout, list);
```

since `stdout` is simply a `FILE*` for standard output (and you can also use `stderr` if you wish). If you want to write it to a file:

```
FILE *fp = fopen ("output_file.txt", "w");
if (fp == NULL) {
    // Flag an error.
} else {
    list_print (fp, list);
    fclose (fp);
}
```

There's also a change you can make to get rid of the extraneous space at the end of each line when the particular list is not empty. At the moment, a list (1,2,3) will print as (the `_` characters are spaces):

```
1_2_3_
```

If you change the function to be:

```
void list_print(FILE *fOut, INTLIST* list) {
    INTLIST *temp;
    char *sep = "";
    for (temp = list; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next) {
        fprintf (fOut, "%s%d", sep, temp->datum);
        sep = " ";
    }
    fprintf (fOut, "\n");
}
```

it will get rid of that extraneous space at the end. Whether this is actually necessary is a decision for you to make - I've often done this to have a specific output format without making the code too much uglier but it may well be that the space at the end doesn't cause you any trouble.

Answer (score 1):

`list_print` needs to use `fprintf` or it's output will got to standard out rather than to the file.

Which means you need to pass `ofp` as a parameter to `list_print`

also, it makes no sense to fprintf(..., list_print()), since list_doesn't return anything.
just call list_print in that loop.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to print out the result of list_print(), which is void.

You'll need to write a new version of your list_print function, which accepts a FILE* and a list, and replace `printf` there with `fprintf`

To save the common code, you could replicate your original by something like the following:

```
void list_fprint (FILE * out, INTLIST * list) {
   . . . // as described above
}

void list_print (INTLIST * list) {
   list_fprint(stdout, list);
}
```